# fire an alert when a UILocalNotification is called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilocalnotification

I have a UILocalNotification and I want to fire an alert when the app recovers from background to foreground. I can create the alert in didReceiveLocalNotification, but this method can only be called when the app is active. Now I want to check if a notification was fired while the app is in background and then fire an alert when the app recovers.

this is my current method

```
   - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
   {

 // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSLog(@"prefs %@",[prefs stringForKey:@"kTimerNotificationUserDef"]);

if([prefs stringForKey:@"kTimerNotificationUserDef"] != nil)
{
    [prefs setObject:nil forKey:@"kTimerNotificationUserDef"];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Timer Alert" message:[prefs stringForKey:@"kTimerNotificationUserDef"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];
  }
}
```

the NSUserDefaults is set when I initialize the notification, however, this alert is called even though the notification did not arrive yet. So, Im assuming maybe I can do something like:

```
   if([prefs stringForKey:@"kTimerNotificationUserDef"] != nil && didFireNotifFromBackground)
```

any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

 notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
 NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
 [viewController showReminder:reminderText];
 }
```

show the alertview where class u want to show

```
- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text 
{

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" message:text delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
}
```

Comment: didReceiveLocalNotification cannot be called when the app is in background.

Comment: Refer from Here http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/7/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html

Comment: I tried that sample project but I'm not getting the alert when the app recovers from background to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

It is in your settings. Settings ->Notification->Your application in right side-> Choose your alert style.

Then you get alert directly while firing local notification